# How to check if record exists in blade?

Tags: php, laravel

I have table for customer and want to redirect to a page if package equal to 1 and customer id equal to current customer id, well I know how to use code for users table but don't know how to use it for customers
**for users:**

```
@if(auth()->user()->package== 1)
```

I don't know what **( ->user() )** means!!!
what I have to create to let this work for customers?
Im sorry Im new in laravel :(

Comment: I suggest you start with reading authentication docs if you don't know what the user() method does - https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication

Comment: I suggest @jedrzej.kurylo read up on docs also understanding how controllers and the User class works so you can place functions inside if you want.

Comment: `auth()->user()` is the user model for the currently authenticated user. Read up more on authentication and eloquent and you will get a better idea on what's happening

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ Auth::user()->name }}
```

Using Auth facade can access authenticated user data

Comment: I know its strange question but here Im talking about table has relationship with users tables

Answer (score 0):

You can create a relationship between users and customer table and then check the same as per your requirement for more information check 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships